# How i can save div text for use in another place?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I need save div text value and after it assert in another place?

```
cy.get('div').should(($div) => {
    const myText = $div.innerText
})
cy.get('.value').should('have.text', myText)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress is asynchronous. What this means is that if you do something like this:

```js
cy.get('div').should(($div) => {
  const myText = $div.innerText
})
cy.get('.value').should('have.text', myText)
```

...your test will always fail. `const myText = $div.innerText` will be executed *after* the `.should('have.text', myText)` is evaluated.

If you want to use `myText` in this way, just use the Promise returned by [`cy.get()`](https://on.cypress.io/get):

```js
cy.get('div')
.then($div => {
  const myText = $div.text()
  // write the rest of your test here
  cy.get('.value').should('have.text', myText)
})
```

Comment: i need use text value later, on another page

Comment: @Kkkk you can put the redirect (`cy.visit`) command into the `.then()` callback as well, so that you then have access to the `myText` value. Alternatively, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55919048/927631) for other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your snippet is that you are not chaining it and hence you are losing the value at last statement. Basically you have to chain it in order to use in subsequent steps.

```
let tempValue = "";
cy.get('div').each(($div) => {
  tempValue = $div.text();
  }).then(() => {
       cy.get('.value').should('have.text', tempValue)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you write a simple javascript function in `commands.js` file and return the `text`.
Now you can call the `commands.js` function where ever and when ever you needed.

/ cypress/support/commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getText', () => {
 cy.visit('/');
 cy.get('div')
  .then($div => {
  const myText = $div.text();
    return myText;
  })
});
```

// This is your test file 1, for example 'test-spec-1.js'

```
describe('Test spec-1', function() {
  it('Receive first time ', function() {
   cy.visit('/');
   const someText1 = cy.getText(); 
...
  })
})
```

// This is your test file 2, for example 'test-spec-2.js'

```
describe('Test spec-2', function() {
  it('Receive second time', function() {
   cy.visit('/');
   const someText2 = cy.getText(); 
.....
  })
})
```